# Count of number of locations within certain distance

Tags: python, dataframe, conditional-statements

I have a dataframe named SD_Apartments that has 3 variables: name (object), latitude (float64), longitude (float64). It's a list of apartment names, and their coordinates.

I have another dataframe named SD_Coffee that has 3 variables: name (object), latitude (float64), longitude (float64). It's a list of coffee shop names, and their coordinates.

I want to add another variable to SD_apartments called coffee_count that would have the number of coffee shop locations listed in my SD_coffee dataframe that are within x (for example, 300) meters from each apartment listed in SD_apartments.

Here is a setup of the code I'm working with:

```py
import pandas as pd
import geopy.distance
from geopy.distance import geodesic

data = [['Insomnia', 32.784782, -117.129130], ['Starbucks', 32.827521, -117.139966], ['Dunkin', 32.778519, -117.154720]]
data1 = [['DreamAPT', 32.822090, -117.184200], ['OKAPT', 32.748081, -117.130691], ['BadAPT', 32.786886, -117.097536]]
SD_Coffee = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ['name', 'latitude', 'longitude'])
SD_Apartments = pd.DataFrame(data1, columns = ['name', 'latitude', 'longitude'])
```

Here is the code I'm attempting to use to accomplish my goal:

```py
def geodesic_pd(df1, df2_row):
    return [(geodesic([tuple(x) for x in row.values], [tuple(x) for x in df2_row.values]).m for row in df1)] 

SD_Apartments['coffee_count'] = pd.Series([(sum(geodesic_pd(SD_Coffee[['latitude', 'longitude']], row) < 300) for row in SD_Apartments[['latitude', 'longitude']])])
```

If you run it and print SD_Apartments, you will see that SD_Apartments looks like:

```py
       name  ...                                       coffee_count
0  DreamAPT  ...  <generator object <genexpr> at 0x000002E178849...
1     OKAPT  ...                                                NaN
2    BadAPT  ...                                                NaN
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you are using pandas dataframes, you should be able to use something like this unless you have very large arrays -

```
import numpy as np

def geodesic_pd(df1, df2_row):
    dist = []
    for _, row in df1.iterrows():
        dist.append(geodesic(tuple(row.values), tuple(df2_row.values)).m)
    return np.array(dist)

SD_Apartments['coffee_count'] = SD_Apartments.apply(lambda row: sum(geodesic_pd(SD_Coffee[['latitude', 'longitude']], row[['latitude', 'longitude']]) < 300), axis =1)
```

The `geodesic_pd` functions extends the geodesic calculation to a dataframe from individual tuples to a dataframe, and the next statement calculates the number of coffee stores within 300 meters and stores them in a new column.

If you have large arrays, then you should combine KNN in order to only perform this operation over a subset of points.

Comment: I'm really sorry for needing more help than you've already so generously given me, but I'm having trouble with this. I've simply copy and pasted the code you've supplied me into Python (Spyder) and I am receiving "SyntaxError: Generattor expression must be parenthesized". I've seen that I may need to update django, so i ran pip install django==1.11.17, and the error persists. My main question is, is the code you supplied meant to be straight copy and pasted, or do I need to change parts of the syntax? It appeared that it was ready to go, but again, I have no idea what I'm doing.

Comment: It probably is not a Django issue and you should not need to install Django if you don't have it already. I have updated the code above by adding parenthesis which should make it work. If it still does not work, can you please provide more information about the error?

Comment: Alright so I got the first two lines to work (the "tuple....values" needed to each be bracketed), but now the last line is giving me the error "ValueError: Length of values does not match length of index"...

Comment: I have updated the answer to reflect what you mentioned. In order to debug the error, please check if the length of the list from the right side of the assignment operation matches the size of your dataframe. Please provide a minimal, complete and verifiable example as per stackoverflow guidelines if you want us to debug further otherwise the solution is just based on what I think should work but I have no way of debugging it.

Comment: Hi, I edited the question such that it (hopefully) satisfies these guidelines. I will make sure to do this in the future. Thank you for correcting.

Comment: Thanks for updating. I was successfully able to debug and edited my response with code that should work now.

Answer (score 1):

This will probably help you:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'geodesic': [1, 10, 8, 11, 20,2,2],'apartment': list('aaceeee')})
df.nsmallest(3, 'geodesic')
```

Another way of doing this is by using `K-Nearest neighbors` using the geodesic distance:

[SKLearn-KNN](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/neighbors/plot_classification.html#sphx-glr-auto-examples-neighbors-plot-classification-py)